# Why are my \include files ignored?

Tags: include

I am trying to use the \include command to import chapters into Latex. For some reason, Latex is completely ignoring files in the \include command. If I replace \include with \input they are included fine, why might this be? FOr information I am using TeXnicCenter on windows. It fails for both Latex and pdflatex.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{report} 

\begin{document}

% Ignored
\include{./integrated_linear_generator_models.tex}

% Works
\input{./integrated_linear_generator_models.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the `./` out of the paths?

Comment: Did you try without the `./`? I remember windows LaTeX sometimes being confused with the slash, backslash.

Comment: Actually I've just discovered it works if I remove the '.tex' from the filename!! Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @crobar: Yes, the `.tex` is always optional but not allowed for `\include`. The reason is that it also creates a `<name>.aux` file and needs the name without extension for that.

Comment: ok, I hadn't come across that in any of the places I'd found documentation on the \include command (first two results of google). Thanks, by the way.

Comment: Ok, I posted it as an answer, so that the question can be officially concluded.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The issue is the `.tex` extension. It is always optional and will be added automatically. However, in the case of `\include` is is not be allowed. The reason is that it also creates a `<name>.aux` file and needs the name without extension for that. Otherwise it will create `<name>.tex.aux` and try to read `` `<name>.tex.tex ``, which causes the error.

You should also try to avoid the `./` which might cause also some issues and isn't required as well.

So simply use:

```
\include{integrated_linear_generator_models}
```

Comment: Registered to say thank you, Martin!

Comment: Using vscode I had to go back and delete the temp files from when I include the `.tex` extension